# audio_players in flutter isn't working on a source url

Tags: flutter, package, flutter-audioplayers

I am building an music player application that takes the URL from a php local host server and play it
The package I am using is audio_player and it can play audio files either from assets in application or using a URL
when I tried to play assets audio file it worked perfectly
but a URL doesn't work

```
import 'dart:ui';
import 'package:audioplayers/audioplayers.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tahween/api/linkAPI.dart';
class MusicPlayer extends StatefulWidget{
  const MusicPlayer({super.key});
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() =>MusicPlayerState();
}
class MusicPlayerState extends State<MusicPlayer> {
    final audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
    Duration duration = Duration.zero;
    Duration position = Duration.zero;
    bool isPlaying = false;
    IconData playIcon = Icons.play_arrow;
  @override
  void initState() {
            super.initState();
    audioPlayer.onPlayerStateChanged.listen((state) {
      setState(() {
      isPlaying = state ==PlayerState.playing;
      playIcon = playIcon==Icons.play_arrow?Icons.pause:Icons.play_arrow;
      });
    });
    audioPlayer.onDurationChanged.listen((newDuration) {
      setState(() {
        duration=newDuration;
      });
    });
  audioPlayer.onPositionChanged.listen((newPosition) {
    setState(() {
      position=newPosition;
    });
    });
    print("ready");
      }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    double screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    double screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    return Scaffold(
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          SizedBox(
            height: screenHeight,
            width: screenWidth,
            child: Image.asset(
              "lib/images/music player.jpg", // Original clear image
              fit: BoxFit.fill,
            ),
          ),
          Positioned.fill(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ImageFilter.blur(
                  sigmaX: 10.0,
                  sigmaY: 10.0), // Adjust blur intensity as needed
              child: Container(
                color:
                    Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5), // Adjust opacity as needed
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Positioned(
            top: screenHeight / 10,
            left: screenWidth / 10,
            right: screenWidth / 10,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight / 2,
                  child: ClipRRect(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(
                        30.0), 
                    child: Image.asset("lib/images/music player.jpg",
                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight / 20,
                ),
                SliderTheme(
                  data: SliderTheme.of(context).copyWith(
                    activeTrackColor: Colors.white,
                    thumbColor: Colors.white,
                    inactiveTrackColor: Colors.black
                  ),
                  child: Slider(
                    value: position.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    min: 0,
                    max: duration.inSeconds.toDouble(),
                    onChanged: (value) async{
                      final position = Duration(seconds: value.toInt());
                      await audioPlayer.seek(position);
                      await audioPlayer.resume();
                      
                    },),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight / 20,
                ),
                Row(
                  //control buttons
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: Icon(CupertinoIcons.shuffle,color: Colors.grey[500],)),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.backward_end_alt_fill,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                    InkWell(
                        onTap: (){
                        if(isPlaying){
                          print("pause");
                           audioPlayer.pause();
                        } else{
                          // https://youtu.be/TvUvq2SnTtA
                          Source src= UrlSource(musicURL);
                          audioPlayer.play(src);
                          print("play");
                        }
                      },
                      child: Container(
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(100),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                        height: screenWidth / 7,
                        width: screenWidth / 7,
                        child: Icon(
                          playIcon,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        child: const Icon(
                          CupertinoIcons.forward_end_alt_fill,
                          color: Colors.black,
                        )),
                    IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.repeat, color: Colors.grey[500],))
                  ],
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  height: screenHeight / 20,
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Song name",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 30,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Don't forget to close your eyes!",
                  style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.white,
                      fontSize: 17,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
                const Text(
                  "Duration",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[Source Set Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bHnXZ.png)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you're trying to play a youtube as an audiosource, by the way I look at your comments

```
// https://youtu.be/TvUvq2SnTtA
Source src= UrlSource(musicURL);
audioPlayer.play(src);
```

Unfortunately audioplayers does not work that way! You should include the right url that is an actual sound file url (wav, mp3,... if you know what i mean)

If by any case the actual sound file URL works when opening with the browser and not the simulator (example: using Chrome is fine but ios simulator fails), check in the type of the sounds.

Answer (score 0):

put the source URL into initstate
`@override` void initState() {
super.initState();
audioPlayer = AudioPlayer();
audioPlayer.setSourceUrl('https://www.example.com/');}`